# Arbitrary number of 3d points how to zip to get x,y,z for plotting

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I'm trying to plot a figure in 3D given an arbitrary number of points

```
import numpy as np
p = [ 
np.array([ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
np.array([10.0, 0.0,10.0]),
np.array([10.0,21.0,10.0]),
np.array([14.5,25.5,14.5]),
np.array([ 0.0,40.0, 0.0]),
np.array([36.0,40.0, 0.0])]
```

... up to p[14]

```
section1 = [4, 0,1,2,3,4]
section2 = [8,14,1,2,8]
```

I need to combine p[4],p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3],p[4] and zip them to get the X,Y,Z I need to plot the lines.

I've been reduced to:

```
X=[]
Y=[]
Z=[]
for i in range(len(section1)):
    X.append(p[section1[i]][0])
    Y.append(p[section1[i]][1])
    Z.append(p[section1[i]][2])
```

Whenever I put the points in a list and zip it, I get a strange list of the original points.

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: What are you doing with `section2`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do that:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p=np.random.rand(50,3)
section=[[21, 13,  2, 36, 20, 15,21],[7, 14, 19, 32,7]]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

color=['red','blue']
for i in range(2):
    x,y,z=p[section[i]].T
    ax.plot(x,y,z,color[i])
plt.show()
```

For :
[image]

Comment: That only works if the sections are the same length. They're not. 

    points=p[section]

gives an IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Comment: Your generation of sections makes them all the same length.  I'm not sure how to generate sections with some 5 and others 6 in length.  My example showed one section with 5 points and one with 6.

 remove: points=p[section] and replace the plot instruction with:

    for i in range(len(section)):
        ax.plot(*p[section[i]].T)

makes it work

Comment: I used your exemple.... Give a more general description to have a more general answer. I update for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Your `p` is a list of arrays:

```
In [566]: p = [ 
     ...: np.array([ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
     ...: np.array([10.0, 0.0,10.0]),
     ...: np.array([10.0,21.0,10.0]),
     ...: np.array([14.5,25.5,14.5]),
     ...: np.array([ 0.0,40.0, 0.0]),
     ...: np.array([36.0,40.0, 0.0])]
In [567]: len(p)
Out[567]: 6
In [568]: section1 = [4, 0,1,2,3,4]
```

I can convert that into a 2d array with `np.stack`:

```
In [569]: arr = np.stack(p)
In [570]: arr.shape
Out[570]: (6, 3)
```

Then it's easy to select rows with the `section1` list:

```
In [571]: arr[section1,:]
Out[571]: 
array([[  0. ,  40. ,   0. ],
       [  0. ,   0. ,   0. ],
       [ 10. ,   0. ,  10. ],
       [ 10. ,  21. ,  10. ],
       [ 14.5,  25.5,  14.5],
       [  0. ,  40. ,   0. ]])
```

`X = arr[section1,0]` and so on.  Though for plotting you might not need to separate out the columns.

Comment: For plotting the transpose of that last array should work.